# Changing the UIReturnKey for an HTML text field in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios6, uikeyboard

We have a UIWebView within our app to ease the pain of creating a large form.  A lot of the text fields produce a keyboard with a "Go" button, but we don't send the user to another page from any text field.  A "Done" button would be more appropriate.

In general, is there a way to customize the UIReturnKey on the keyboard, outside of the usual HTML tags?

Comment: This appears to be partially resolved by removing the `<form>` tags around all the text inputs, and we don't need it because we never POST the data, but I'm still curious if the UIReturnKey is at all customizable.